# How to create "menu grid" in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, menu

I have searched google/stackoverflow etc. for answer to my question, but I didn't quite manage to find the right one. I believe I just don't know, how to set the question properly, and thus I cannot find solution.

Is there any way, how to create grid like I drawed in following image (with red colour):[image: Image with menu grid]

I need to add this red grid to several images, which look very simmilar. The grid field (the one selected) have rolling menu, prescribed position, and a field for additional text. Black lines in background are image in background, and the red supposed to be grid above the image. I thought of creating a lot of buttons alined to each other, but i think that is very bad way to do so.

I would like a pop-up menu from selected field, but opening new activity with same fields is usable aswell. Is there any "simple" solution for creating such grid/menu ?

Btw, I am not programmer with many experience with coding, let's say, I know basics only.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give any context for this? For example, what platform is this for? (Web app? Desktop app in Swing, JavaFX, TornadoFX, Jetpack Compose or whatever? Mobile app for Android or iOS?)

Comment: It's supposed to be Android app only. It will not be distributed in any market, so there is no necessity to make any crossplatform thing.